# Making a clone of windows drive, then erasing and using Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have a windows 10 laptop that only has windows restore saved on a protected partition. I would like to make a "clone" of my whole hard drive and then erase and use Ubuntu. Or should I just try duel booting instead?

Comment: It depends: Do you still want to use Windows or not?

Comment: Windows uses it's own software to clone, repair, and restore disks. So you'll have to clone it in windows, save it as a backup somewhere **not** on the disk you want to erase (like I did at one point in time) and then from there continue like a normal ubuntu installation

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend shrinking Windows to the smallest comfortable size; say 50 or 60 GB. If you are a gamer then 500 GB or so might be comfortable if you have 1 TB HDD or SSD. After shrinking Windows install Ubuntu in dual boot mode.

- You want to keep Windows working for when Ubuntu crashes and you need to use google for repair solutions.
- Windows is superior for gaming. Even if you don't use PC games often, sometimes it's nice to sit back and relax around Christmas with a good game.
- Windows may have BIOS updates and firmware updates from manufacturers that aren't available in Linux. You apply the updates in Windows and it can fix problems in Linux.
- Other people or organizations may send you files that can only be read with a specific Windows application not available on Linux.
- You already think you might need Windows in the future which is why you are backing it up. Should you reinstall Windows that means wiping out Ubuntu and having to reinstall it in dual boot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends. What programs do you use regulary **that you cannot live without** that require Windows?

What percent of your time will you spend using those programs vs the rest of what you will be doing in Linux?

If you think you will spend more of your time using those programs in Windows, then maybe dual boot is the option for you. If you think you will spend most of your time in Linux and only occasionally use Windows for a program or two then you might even consider running Windows in a virtual machine like VirtualBox.

If you wish to clone your computer I would recommend CloneZilla.